# Unable to create Compute Instances on Microsoft Azure on behalf of another user via CLI

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to create a compute instance on behalf of another user using the CLI and a yaml config file. The yaml file is set up as follows:

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/computeInstance.schema.json
name: Lightweight-CPU-Instance
type: computeinstance
size: STANDARD_D2s_v3
idle_time_before_shutdown_minutes: 60
location: uksouth
tags:
  name0: value0
  name1: value1
schedules:
  compute_start_stop:
    - action: stop
      trigger:
        type: cron
        start_time: "2023-05-10T08:00:00"
        time_zone: "UTC"
        expression: "00 21 * * 1,2,3,4,5"
```

I then attempt to deploy the compute instance with the following parameterized CLI function

`az ml compute create -f TestMLComputeInstanceCreate.yaml --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --workspace-name $WorkspaceName --set name=$ComputeInstanceName create_on_behalf_of.user_tenant_id=$TenantID create_on_behalf_of.user_object_id=$ObjectID`

Where params `$ResourceGroupName , $WorkspaceName, $ComputeInstanceName, $TenantID and $ObjectID` are all either input manually or derived from other inputs when executing the function.

Running the function gives me the following error:

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
Validation for ComputeInstanceSchema failed:

 {
  "idle_time_before_shutdown_minutes": [
    "Unknown field."
  ],
  "tags": [
    "Unknown field."
  ]
}
```

I don't understand what's creating this issue. Azure's official documentation shows I should be able to configure auto-shutdown capabilities in the yaml fig ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=azure-cli&view=azureml-api-2#enable-idle-shutdown) and the tags should also be a valid field entry from the [yaml schema that is called in the yaml file](https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/computeInstance.schema.json). VS code Azure ML extension also recognizes both parameters as valid entries when tinkering with the yaml config files.

I'm able to bypass this error by including the `idle_time_before_shutdown_minutes` and `tags` as additional sub-parameters under the `set` parameter for `az ml compute create`, however even though the compute instance will successfully deploy on behalf of my other user, it will not have any idle time shutdown, scheduling or tags assigned to the resource.

Answer (score 1):

With yaml config details and cli command provided in the question. We are able to successfully execute the requirement.
below are the details of version we used:

azure-cli 2.48.1
core 2.48.1
Extensions:
ml 2.15.1

Please check your version details before executing the command again.
If the **idle_time_before_shutdown_minutes** is not showing in existing compute instance, you can execute below command and cli to update your compute instance with schedule property.

```
az rest --method post --url "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION-ID/resourceGroups/RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/WORKSPACE-NAME/computes/INSTANCE-NAME/updateIdleShutdownSetting?api-version=2021-07-01%22" --body '{"idleTimeBeforeShutdown":"PT30M"}'
```

Replace the value of :

- RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME
- WORKSPACE-NAME
- INSTANCE-NAME

and **idle_time_before_shutdown_minutes** can be provided in and as :

`--body '{"idleTimeBeforeShutdown":"PT30M"}'` for **30 minutes**.

**Note:** The acceptable values are PT15M to PT120M for 15 minutes to 2 hours.

Before executing the command

[image]

After executing the command.

[image]